# Java type is unknown in js side

Tags: javascript, java, interop, graalvm

Please help point out what the problem might be in the code below. I have this javascript code (in a file '/arithmetic.js') which I'm testing using GraalVM's Context in java

```
function sum(num, b) {
    return num.add(b)
}

function diff(num, b) {
    return num.sub(b)
}
```

The java side looks like this

```
public class Num {

    final int a;

    public Num(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public int add(int b) {
        return this.a + b;
    }

    public int sub(int b) {
        return this.a - b;
    }
}
```

In the main class, I have

```
Engine engine = Engine.create();
try (Context context = Context.newBuilder().engine(engine).build()) {
    context.eval(Source.newBuilder("js", loadFile("/arithmetic.js"), "arithmetic").build());
    Num ten = new Num(10);
    System.out.printf("10 + 3 = %d%n", ten.add(3)); //<-- just checking

    context.getBindings("js").putMember("num", ten); //<-- is this line even necessary?
    Value getSum = context.getBindings("js").getMember("sum");
    Value result = getSum.execute(ten, 20);
    System.out.println(result.asInt());
}
```

I get the output below:

```
> Task :graalvm-js-app:SampleJs.main() FAILED
10 + 3 = 13
Exception in thread "main" TypeError: invokeMember (add) on example.Num@31e4bb20 failed due to: Unknown identifier: add
    at <js> sum(arithmetic:2:34-43)
```

Comment: Can you show the code for Num?

Comment: I updated with Num class

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, it appears that I needed just one slight tweak when building the context. It's not so obvious but it kinda makes sense in the context of the problem encountered

```
Context.newBuilder().engine(engine).allowAllAccess(true).build()
```

Comment: GraalVM follows a "safe by default" approach. It limits what a language can do within its Context. The idea is that it cannot breach out of its Context - by disallowing file IO, network IO, and also as you experiences, by disallowing access to the host (Java).

You have to explicitly turn on each of those accesses (or, as you do, allowAllAccess) - note that granting such access makes your application less secure. Make sure you know what the application is doing; don't allowAllAccess for code your users can provide.

Comment: Thank you so much Christian for the insight